# ExtJs Get the ID of the drop target

Tags: extjs

I've created an extJs drag and drop tree and I'm attemting to check whether a node exists in a particular branch before it's dropped in. To do this, I'm overwriting a method called `beforeDragDrop()`  ([Link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DragSource.html#method-Ext.dd.DragSource-beforeDragDrop)), which passes in the whole `Target` tree, the `Event` object, and the `Dragged item ID`.

Calling `Event.getTarget()` gives me the the target node of the item adjacent to the dropped item. What I really need is the parent node within the target where this item is dropped, which will allow me to check whether the item already exists within the branch.

**Is there any way of getting the id of a Tree branch within the drop target in ExtJs?**

It's a long shot, but I've been faffing around for ages and could really do with a hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a `parent()` method for the target node?  What kind of object does `getTarget()` return?

Comment: getTarget() returns the HTML element of the node, for example <div id='123' ext:tree-node-id='2010'>Item</div>. The problem is amplified by the fact the id I need is the one generated automatically by ExtJs - ext:tree-node-id, and I can't fathom how to get access to that property - it seems to be created by the JSONLoader when the tree is created.

Comment: In the documentation for `Ext.EventObject`, it seems like `getTarget()`'s third parameter is a boolean that specifies whether it should return an `Ext.Element`.  `Ext.EventObject` is a Static class though, so I don't know if it has the same methods as `Event`, but if the same parameter exists for `Event`, then with the `Ext.Element` you get back, you can call `parent()`.

Comment: Ah nicely done, having the object is exactly what I had wanted. For some reason calling parent() just returns the same node. Have I missed a trick?

Comment: Not sure why `parent()` isn't doing what you want, I would try `up()` with a empty selector to see if it gives different results.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dropposition = tree.getdropPositonModel().getdropPosition();
// put it on AJAX require
params :
{
    dropid : dropposition.data.id // id from getNodes  
}
```